# How to populate UITableView with UISwitch.

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I am using Apple's Sample Code TheElements for this question. The project can be found here: [TheElements](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html)

I would like to know how to populate the "Grouped by State" UITableView using a UISwitch. I have added a UISwitch to the File: AtomicElementFlippedView which will add the selected element to the "Grouped by State" UITableView. Just to clarify I have removed the "Grouped by State" UITableView data. I would like the UITableView to get populated when the user taps the UISwitch to the ON position which will add the selected element into the UITableView.I've done a ton of Googling and it seems there are several ways to go about it, but none seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

GUI:https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt1ZI.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you will need to implement the following methods:

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //This should really be a class in its own right. 
    UIView* headerView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 0); 
    UISwitch* aSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [headerView addSubView:aSwitch];

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 80;
}
```

**What happened?**

We created a UIView container and added a UISwitch to it, returning the UIView as the header view, as per the table view contract.

The headerView created above should really be created as a class in its own right, and you should override layoutSubviews to put the components in their correct location respective to the parent views size. (This is how to do auto-layout in code).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jasper. Unfortunately I am still having issues with my project. If you have time I would really appreciate help writing the complete method.

Comment: Well. . . you just need to create a view and add a switch to it. . updating example. Try to research how to create a UIView with code or load a UIView from a xib.